# Unable to create path for cronjob

Tags: php, cron, cpanel, jobs, cron-task

I am unable to create correct path of my page for cronjob. I want in cronjob run this again and again but I am unable to make correct path of my page. At cronjob page there is notice written :

**PHP command examples:**

> **General example:**
>   `/usr/local/bin/php /home/flipkart/public_html/path/to/cron/script`
>
> **Domain-specific example:**
>   `/usr/local/bin/ea-php56 /home/flipkart/domain_path/path/to/cron/script`
>   *In the above example, replace “ea-php56” with the PHP version assigned to the domain you wish to use. Look in the MultiPHP Manager for the actual PHP version assigned to a domain.*

I am editing like this: 
`/usr/local/bin/ea-php72 /home/flipkart/public_html/folder1/page1.php`

But it not work.please help tell me where I am working wrong. What would correct path.

Comment: Does php is available on this path: /usr/local/bin/ea-php72?

Comment: i usually do it like : php /home/your_user_name/public_html/php_file_to_execute.php

Comment: Yes php is available

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It's usually

```
/usr/bin/php /path/to/file.php
```

Because I have no instance of php in my /usr/local/bin